# Programmatically disable the mobile zoom buttons

Tags: javascript, mobile

I have a web site that displays either a google map or a list of text (they are not separate pages but just 2 divs that I show/hide).

I would like to disable the browser zoom buttons when viewing the map as I dont see that there is much need and it is confusing to see both the map zoom buttons and the browser zoom buttons.

I know does the trick for the whole page (or it least it works for me on android 2.2):
`meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"`

But how do I switch zoom buttons on and off with javascript?

(There is an answer to my question here: [How to enable user-scalable (viewport property) after disabling it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162174/how-to-enable-user-scalable-viewport-property-after-disabling-it/16933635#16933635) but I couldnt get it to work)

Comment: what's wrong with leaving the meta out on the page with the map? that would be the easiest fix. no need to programatically disable it

Comment: @kennypu, the map is not on a separate html page - it is on the same page as the text but is in a div that I show/hide. I need to do this as I have javascript connection between map markers and the list of data

Comment: in that case, I don't think it's possible, since the meta tags go into effect on page load.