# Activate user-scalable only when lightbox active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I am trying to make images inside a lightbox zoomable. The site I am building is responsive, and doesn't need any zooming on mobile. But there are some images, that have quiet some detail, and are hard to read on mobile, even though opened in a light box.

My question is: Is there a way, to enable user-scalable, only for the opened lightbox.
And the second question is: If that is possible, will the whole site zoom, when pinch zoomed, in the lightbox, or is it possible to implement this only for the lightbox layer.

I hope this makes some sense.

I just need some push in the right direction, on how to solve this. Any tips?

Many regards and thanks,
Shumachine

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? thanks

Comment: I ended up using a third party plugin which works quite well on mobile devices.

I can tell you on Saturday which one it was. I am traveling at the moment and will be back tomorrow evening.

Comment: No problem, thanks for answering. I solved it with a few lines of code implementing the suggestion found on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16933635/1571065)

Comment: Awesome - thanks for sharing. I ended up using http://www.swinxyapps.com/pages/apps/swinxy-zoom/

Sorry for the delay.